# How sellect all elements by querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript

I have a website with product catalog
https://www.estelab.ru/cosmetics/zo-medical/

After click to the button "buy" in orange background you can see in console message ("addToCart works")

But this click works with first button.

```js
var CartButton = document.querySelector(".eshop_js-add-to-cart");
CartButton.onclick = (function() {
  console.log("addToCart works");

});
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(".eshop_js-add-to-cart") dont help me in this question

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions in a manner that best enables the community to provide helpful assistance. For what it is worth, I am hesitant to click away to an unknown site for context on a question. Furthermore, if critical information for understanding the problem is on that site and the site gets fixed/updated, this post becomes useless for subsequent visitors. I'd recommend putting a [mcve] as a snippet _in the body of the question_, and include the reproduction steps and expected/actual behavior. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: ok i will correct my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use forEach

```js
var CartButton = document.querySelectorAll(".eshop_js-add-to-cart");

CartButton.forEach((item) => {
  item.onclick = function () {
    console.log("addToCart works");
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart">Click me!</div>
<div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart">Click me!</div>
<div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart">Click me!</div>
<div class="eshop_js-add-to-cart">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: nice. Thank you

Comment: @SadiZeynalov - if this user's answer was helpful, don't forget to upvote it and mark it as your selected answer (if applicable).

Comment: You are welcome, Please mark it as solved. @Sadi Zeynalov

Comment: @emma-teylor how to mark as solved?

Comment: Just click on "Tick" Icon @Sadi Zeynalov

Comment: Can you tell me if i can another document.querySelectorAll into forEach how i can get all the data too

Comment: When you using document.querySelectorAll it's return list of that element and with forEach you can move on that list @Sadi Zeynalov

Comment: can i use document.querySelectorAll into document.querySelectorAll?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @emma-teylor on this page (https://www.estelab.ru/cosmetics/zo-medical/) i have a product list.

After running  script (which do you answer) i need to get a next properties: 


var NameProductList = document.querySelectorAll(".eshop-item-v2-title").textContent;
var ProductIdList = document.querySelectorAll('.eshop_js-add-to-cart');
var ProductIdCountList = ProductIdList.getAttribute('data-id');